# Yum dependency available but not marked for install

Tags: mysql, yum, dependencies

I'm trying to install a specific version of MySQL: `mysql-community-server-5.6.29-2.el6` on RedHat 6.6.

When I run `yum install`, I get dependency errors, **but the dependencies are clearly available**. I'm not sure how to proceed.

It looks like something is requesting `MySQL-community-libs-5.7.11-1.el6`, but I don't know how to force it not to.

Useful output:

```
[root@cl-mgr01 ~]# yum install mysql-community-server-5.6.29-2.el6
     ## truncated for brevity ##
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.29-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.29-2.el6 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) = 5.6.29-2.el6 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnuma.so.1(libnuma_1.2)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnuma.so.1(libnuma_1.1)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnuma.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.29-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) = 5.6.29-2.el6 for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.29-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package numactl.x86_64 0:2.0.9-2.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.29-2.el6 will be obsoleting
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.73-3.el6_5 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.7.11-1.el6 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.11-1.el6 for package: mysql-community-libs-5.7.11-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64 0:5.7.11-1.el6 will be obsoleting
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.29-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.29-2.el6 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.29-2.el6 for package: mysql-community-libs-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.7.11-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql)
           Requires: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.29-2.el6
              ...
           Available: mysql-community-common-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql)
               mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.29-2.el6
              ...
           Installing: mysql-community-common-5.7.11-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql)
               mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.11-1.el6
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql)
           Requires: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.29-2.el6
             ...
           Available: mysql-community-common-5.6.29-2.el6.x86_64 (mysql)
               mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.29-2.el6
             ...
           Installing: mysql-community-common-5.7.11-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql)
               mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.11-1.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Other useful output:

```
[root@cl-mgr01 ~]# rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-6.el6.noarch
mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do in the end is the following:

- Upgrade MySQL-libs using `yum update mysql-libs`, which installed `mysql-community-libs`
- Downgrade them using `yum downgrade mysql-libs` so that they were on 5.6.29
- Install mysql-community-server

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
# yum install --enablerepo=mysql56-community install mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, nvidia
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.metrocast.net
 * elrepo: mirror.symnds.com
 * epel: mirror.metrocast.net
 * extras: mirror.metrocast.net
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: mirror.solarvps.com
No package install available.
Package mysql-community-server-5.6.30-2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
#
```

... better yet, using `yum-config-manager`, disable `mysql57-community` and enable `mysql56-community`, then install `mysql-community-server`.

```
# yum repolist | grep mysql
mysql-connectors-community/x86_64 MySQL Connectors Community                 21
mysql-tools-community/x86_64      MySQL Tools Community                      33
mysql56-community/x86_64          MySQL 5.6 Community Server                229
# egrep '^(name|\[|enabled)' /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo 
[mysql-connectors-community]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
enabled=1
[mysql-tools-community]
name=MySQL Tools Community
enabled=1
[mysql55-community]
name=MySQL 5.5 Community Server
enabled=0
[mysql56-community]
name=MySQL 5.6 Community Server
enabled=1
[mysql57-community-dmr]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server Development Milestone Release
enabled=0
#
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add: this is not on an internet-connected network, and the reposerver is outside my control...